# proof that Riemann integrals is extended by Lebesgue integrals

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, proof-verification

After reading a proof sketch somewhere (forgot the link) I've written a proof in my own words. I'm not quite sure if I got the details right, since there were variants of this floating around that any Riemann integrable function is the pointwise limit of step functions which is false I think. It would be great if anyone could verify this!

We want to prove that $\int_A f d \lambda = \int_a^b f (x) d x$ for $f$ Riemann integrable and $A=(a,b]$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $s = \sum_{i = 1}^m c_i {\bf 1}_{(a_i, b_i]}$ where $(a_i, b_i]$
partitions $A$, then $\int_a^b s (x) d x = \int_a^b c_i {\bf 1}_{(a_i,
b_i]} d x = \sum_{i = 1}^m c_i (b_i - a_i)$, also $\int_A s d \lambda =
\sum_{i = 1}^m c_i (b_i - a_i)$ by definition of Lebesgue integrals and the
Lebesgue measure.

Now since $f$ is Riemann integrable, there are bounded step functions $\phi_k
\uparrow \phi \leqslant f$ and $\psi_k \downarrow \psi \geqslant f$ on $[a,
b]$ s.t. $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^b \phi_k (x) d x = \lim_{k
\rightarrow \infty} \int_a^b \psi_k (x) d x = \int_a^b f (x) d x$. By the
dominated convergence theorem, $\int_A \phi d \lambda = \lim_{k \rightarrow
\infty} \int_A \phi_k d \lambda = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^b \phi_k
(x) d x = \int_a^b f (x) d x$, similarly $\int_a^b f (x) d x = \int_A \psi d
\lambda$.

Since $\int_A \phi d \lambda = \int_A \psi d \lambda$ and $\phi \leqslant f
\leqslant \psi$, $\phi \overset{\text{a.e.}}{=} \lambda
\overset{\text{a.e.}}{=} f$, hence $f \in L^1$ and $\int_A f d \lambda =
\int_a^b f (x) d x$.

Comment: Search in books.google.com by _comparison riemann lebesgue_.